# Laravel find data by model

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying to debug data when i try to edit some column on database for example id such as `1`, when i run this url on address bar:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/content_category/1/edit
```

i get this result:

```
ContentCategories {#246 ▼
  #table: "contents_categories"
  #guarded: array:1 [▶]
  #connection: null
  #primaryKey: "id"
  #keyType: "int"
  +incrementing: true
  #with: []
  #withCount: []
  #perPage: 15
  +exists: false
  +wasRecentlyCreated: false
  #attributes: []
  #original: []
  #changes: []
  #casts: []
  #dates: []
  #dateFormat: null
  #appends: []
  #dispatchesEvents: []
  #observables: []
  #relations: []
  #touches: []
  +timestamps: true
  #hidden: []
  #visible: []
  #fillable: []
}
```

data is `null` in this result and i don't have any information about `id=1`

this column of data is exist on database and i checked that with `phpmyadmin`, my `edit` function on controller is:

```
public function edit(ContentCategories $contentCategories)
{
    dd($contentCategories);
}
```

and `Model` in project:

```
class ContentCategories extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'contents_categories';
    protected $guarded = ['id'];
}
```

route:

```
Route::resource('content_category', 'ContentCategoriesController');
```

Comment: can you provide your route definition

Comment: @lagbox `Route::resource('content_category', 'ContentCategoriesController');`

Comment: @lagbox and post updated

Comment: do a `php artisan route:list` to check how its being defined, what is the parameter it ends up using in the URI? this is important for implicit model binding

Comment: @lagbox i get this output `content_category/{content_category}/edit | content_category.edit    | App\Http\Controllers\ContentCategoriesController@edit`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to update your method signatures to be able to use implicit route model binding here.

> "Laravel automatically resolves Eloquent models defined in routes or controller actions whose type-hinted variable names match a route segment name." [Laravel 5.5 Docs - Routing - Implicit Model Binding](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/routing#implicit-binding)

```
public function edit(ContentCategories $content_category)
```

This matches the route parameter name to your type hinted parameter name. This will allow for the binding to happen. Without this matching of the names of these parameters the typehinted parameter you have is being resolved as a new instance of that model via dependency injection. It has to resolve the dependency so you get a new model instance because it doesn't know that it is the parameter you want the binding for.

**Additional information:**

> "By default, `Route::resource` will create the route parameters for your resource routes based on the 'singularized' version of the resource name."

[Laravel 5.5 Docs - Controllers - Resource Controllers - Naming Resource Route Parameters](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/controllers#restful-naming-resource-route-parameters)

Comment: could you help me why in this code i get empty array?  `public function show(Contents $manage_contents)
    {
        dd($manage_contents);
    }`, my route is: `Route::resource('manage_contents', 'ContentsController');` and urls is: `http://127.0.0.1:8000/manage_contents/5` Thanks in advance

Comment: same answer as before ... run `php artisan route:list` and see how the route is being registered

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your controller edit method

```
public function edit($id)
{
    $contentCategories = ContentCategories::find($id);
    dd($contentCategories);
}
```